# Pandas search if input is in Column Values

Tags: python, pandas

| BARCODE | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 12345,98765 | RandomItem1 |
| 45678 | RandomItem2 |

RandomItems can have multiple barcodes. What's the best approach to search & print if the barcode input or part of it exists?

```
barcode=input("Enter or Scan Barcode: ")
        if barcode in ufo.values:
            print(ufo.loc[ufo['BARCODE'] == barcode])
        #if barcode==45678 it will print 45678 RandomItem2
        #if barcode==12345,98765 it will print 12345,98765 RandomItem1
        #if barcode==98765 it wont get results
#NEW TO PYTHON
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rework your dataframe to get one row per barcode:

```
df2 = (df.assign(BARCODE=df['BARCODE'].str.strip().str.split(','))
         .explode('BARCODE')
       )
df2
```

output:

```
  BARCODE  Description
0   12345  RandomItem1
0   98765  RandomItem1
1   45678  RandomItem2
```

then you can use:

```
'12345' in df2['BARCODE'].values
```

output: `True`

Comment: This is not a bad approach! But it will cause a chaos in future append. For example if i want to add a new barcode to the RandomItem1 i ll have to add new row with Description RandomItem1 and the new barcode. So it should be better to keep multiple Barcodes to same Descriptions

Comment: Well you can keep your dataframe with multi-barcodes, just run the above logic when doing your search. Furthermore, if you set barcode as index of df2 you can access the description.